# How to modify package before installing it with pip

Tags: python, windows, pip

Trying to install a package on Windows fails, as it requires a `site.cfg` file to contain the path of a library.

It looks like pip extracts packages to `c:\users\[username]\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-[random string]\` during installation and deletes after installation (successful or not), so I can't "hot-edit" it.

Can I make `pip` wait for me before installing?

Can I make `pip` download and unpack the package and afterwards tell it to install a package from a directory rather than a package name or URL?

*Feel free to comment alternative solutions for installing scikits.audiolab on Windows (demands sndfile to be defined in site.cfg).*

Comment: Isn't it easier to just write the path of the library to `~/.numpy-site.cfg` or `site-packages/numpy/site.cfg`? I mean, even if you manage to find the right spots and patch them, you will still need to build `audiolab` from source then, which is anything but trivial on windows. And of course you won't be able to properly modify prebuilt binary wheels.

Answer (score 1):

Does not work on wheels (see @hoefling comment)

- Download package from url (pip tells you the url when you do `pip install <package_name>`)
- Untar the file and do your modifications
- Then do `pip install <path_of_package>`

Comment: 1. Beware that this will only work with packages that provide source dists, not wheels. 2. `pip install -e` will perform an editable install, which is most surely not what you want. Omit the `-e` flag when installing from source dir.